# Formal Proof of Convergence or Divergence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

How to prove formally that the following series converges or diverges.

$$ \sum_{n=0}^\infty  \frac{\sin n}{2n^2+n}$$

I believe it converges, but as far as proving it formally I would appreciate if some one included a "first step". I am new to the topic and do not have any worked examples using trigonometric functions.

Comment: The sequence definitely converges, but is there a way I can use the Monotone Convergence Theorem to prove it. I know I need to show that that it is increasing or decreasing and then show that it is bounded. The showing it is bounded part is where I am having some trouble. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3):

Note that 
$$
\frac{\sin(n)}{2n^2 + n} < \frac{1}{2n^2 + n} < \frac{1}{n^2} 
$$
and the latter series converges so the former converges absolutely hence converges.